# Storing an integer, adding to itself, and using it as a parameter in a method in java

Tags: java, methods

I have a problem where I have to store an integer, if a user answers Y, from an input and then using it on a method, storing that integer and then adding it to a different input from the user. The total will be used on the same method and printed only if the user inputs N.

For instance,

```
Y
input =3
method(input)
Y
input =  4
method(input)
N
total = 3+4
method(input, total)
```

I have most of the code already, I just want to know if it is possible to get the total and use it on the method

Edit: here is the code

```
public static boolean walk(boolean bool, String answer) { 
      while(bool==true) { 
          if (answer.equals("Y") || answer.equals("y")) { 
              return bool=true;
              }   
          else if (answer.equals("N") || answer.equals("n")) { 
              return bool=true;
              }  
          }
      return bool;
      }
 public static boolean continueWalking(boolean bool, String answer, int average) { 
      while(bool==true){
          if (answer.equals("Y") || answer.equals("y")){
              return bool=true;
              }
          else if(answer.equals("N") || answer.equals("n")){
              System.out.println("Great exercise!"); 
              System.out.println(average);
              System.exit(0); 
              }
          }
      return bool;
      }
while(bool) {
          System.out.println("Do you want to start/continue walking?");
          String continueWalk=input.next();
          int totsteps=numberOfSteps;
          continueWalking(true, continueWalk,totsteps);
          System.out.println("How many steps do you want to walk in this section?");
          totsteps=numberOfSteps + numberOfSteps;
          int numberOfSteps = input.nextInt();
          NumOfsteps(numberOfSteps,1);
          }
```

Comment: "I have most of the code already" -- Can we see it? As a [mcve]?

Comment: `I have most of the code already` ... then show the code along with your question

Comment: I added my code for clarification

Comment: FYI: You should use [`equalsIgnoreCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-).

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of syntax/formatting things to start with:
your while statement `while(bool==true)` can be changed to just `while(bool)`. A while loop statement just needs to evaluate to a `boolean` in Java, and `boolean bool` is already a boolean. You can do a similar thing for your return statements, change them to `return bool;`

To answer your question, to update an `int` value in Java, use `+=`.

```
int test = 0;
test += 1;
System.out.println(test); // Prints out 1
```

In your code, declare `totsteps` outside of the `while` loop, and change the line `int totsteps=numberOfSteps;` to `totsteps += numberOfSteps;`